# How to remove partially uploaded file to Onedrive using Microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

A file was partially uploaded to Onedrive using Microsoft graph API, because of some internet issue. Now the uploaded file is incomplete and has some temporary extension. The file size is more than 10MB, and only few MBs has been uploaded.

the request look like following:

```
POST /drive/root:/{item-path}:/createUploadSession
```

My question is how to get rid of such file using graph API.

Is there any way to provide such information along with the request to remove such file if it fails to upload completely after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can send a `DELETE` to the upload session URL.

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createuploadsession#cancel-the-upload-session):

> To cancel an upload session send a `DELETE` request to the upload URL. This cleans up the temporary file holding the data previously uploaded. This should be used in scenarios where the upload is aborted, for example, if the user cancels the transfer.
>
> Temporary files and their accompanying upload session are automatically cleaned up after the `expirationDateTime` has passed. Temporary files may not be deleted immediately after the expiration time has elapsed.

Comment: Does this stands true for less than 4 MB file as well, which doesn't require upload session; because we do not get any upload URL to send DELETE request.

Comment: If you're noting using an upload session then you either a) have a file that completed that you could `DELETE` or b) the upload failed so no file was ever created. The only reason for deleting an upload session is that you may have a partial upload taking up space. If you don't have an upload  session then this wouldn't be needed.

Comment: today I was uploading a 2.5 MB file, after sending request I lost internet connection, so there is no way I get any response but I see a 1.5 MB file in my One-drive with same name. I waited enough for this file to get deleted from my account, but it is still in my account, corrupted. Is there any way to get rid of such file?

Comment: Once the file is showing up, you should be able to simply issue a `DELETE` for that file id.